postgresql - get cumulative count, in for loop?
In postgresql, how to get cumulative count? I wanted to get a cumulative count of customers enrolled between 01-01 and 02-01, 01-01 and 03-01, 01-01 and 04-01 etc.,
Not sure if we can do for loop like in Python? I checked out a few for loop posts but am lost
select count(distinct customer)
from mytable
where enrollment_dt between '2023-01-01' and '2023-xx-01' 
(this xx will increase by 1 month in each run, like 02-01, 03-01, 04-01...)

so ideally the output should be like:



date
count




01/01-02/01
10


01/01-03/01
12


01/01-04/01
15


01/01-05/01
19


...
...




This can be done in SQL, and shouldn't require a loop (well, the counting at least).

could you maybe shed a light pls?

The feature you want is "group by".

SQL is a set-based language.  You don't loop your records.

Looks like you need a window function to do a running sum over the normal aggregation.
select
  count(distinct mt.customer) as count,
  sum(count(distinct mt.customer)) over (order by mt.enrollment_dt rows unbounded preceding) as running_count
from mytable mt
where mt.enrollment_dt between '2023-01-01' and '2023-xx-01' 


It is not quite clear what exactly you want to do. I took a blind guess and could offer solutions for two possible options. To test it - lets assume that your sample data could be like this:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
CREATE TABLE customers 
(
    id Int, 
    customer Varchar(64), 
    enrollment_dt Date
);

INSERT INTO customers
VALUES (101, 'Customer 101', '2022-11-17'), 
       (102, 'Customer 102', '2022-12-03'), 
       (103, 'Customer 103', '2023-01-17'), 
       (104, 'Customer 104', '2023-01-09'), 
       (105, 'Customer 105', '2023-03-01'), 
       (106, 'Customer 106', '2023-04-03'), 
       (107, 'Customer 107', '2023-04-21'), 
       (108, 'Customer 108', '2023-04-29'),
       (109, 'Customer 109', '2023-07-01');

There are months with and without newly enrolled customers. So you maybe want to select just the rows with new enrollments:
--  Option 1.  - get only the data for months having newly enrolled customer(s)
--      S Q L :
SELECT
    yr_mnth, mnth_count,
    SUM(mnth_count) OVER (ORDER BY yr_mnth
                          Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) AS running_sum
FROM   
    (SELECT
         To_Char(Date_Trunc('month', enrollment_dt), 'yyyy-mm') AS yr_mnth, 
         COUNT(*) AS mnth_count
     FROM 
         customers
     WHERE
         enrollment_dt >= '2023-01-01'
     GROUP BY
         yr_mnth)
ORDER BY 
    yr_mnth

Result:
yr_mnth mnth_count  running_sum
------- ----------  -----------
2023-01          2            2
2023-03          1            3
2023-04          3            6
2023-07          1            7  */

... on the other hand maybe you want to select all the months in certain period regardless new enrollments...
For this you will need a sort of calendar of months in period...
--  Option 2.  - get the data for all months regardless there were newly enrolled customer(s) or not
--  Use Recursive CTE to generate rows with all the months in period of interest
WITH
    Recursive mnths ( month_id ) as
        ( Select Date_Trunc('month', Cast('2023-01-01' as Date)) as month_id 
         UNION ALL
          Select month_id + interval '1 month' 
          From mnths
          Where month_id < Date_Trunc('month', Current_Date)
        )

... the calendar data should be joined to the sql from Option 1. (Left Join) handling the Null values...
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select     To_Char(m.month_id, 'yyyy-mm') as yr_mnth, 
           Coalesce(c.mnth_count, 0) as mnth_count,
           Coalesce(c.running_sum, Max(running_sum) Over(Order By To_Char(m.month_id, 'yyyy-mm')
                                       Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding)) as running_sum
From       mnths m 
Left Join  ( SELECT    yr_mnth, mnth_count,
                       Sum(mnth_count) 
                           Over(Order By yr_mnth
                           Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as running_sum
             FROM   ( Select    To_Char(Date_Trunc('month', enrollment_dt), 'yyyy-mm') as yr_mnth, 
                                Count(*) as mnth_count
                      From      customers
                      Where     enrollment_dt >= '2023-01-01'
                      Group By  yr_mnth
                   )
           ) c ON(c.yr_mnth = To_Char(m.month_id, 'yyyy-mm'))
Order By   To_Char(m.month_id, 'yyyy-mm')

/*    R e s u l t : 
yr_mnth mnth_count  running_sum
------- ----------  -----------
2023-01          2            2
2023-02          0            2
2023-03          1            3
2023-04          3            6
2023-05          0            6
2023-06          0            6
2023-07          1            7
2023-08          0            7
2023-09          0            7
2023-10          0            7
2023-11          0            7
2023-12          0            7
2024-01          0            7
2024-02          0            7
2024-03          0            7
2024-04          0            7
2024-05          0            7
2024-06          0            7
2024-07          0            7   */

See the fiddle here.
